url rewrite - How do I redirect everything below the folder level
I'm trying to do an url rewrite in an old asp.net webforms app.  I'm using the iis url rewrite module from msft.  I'm not experienced with the url rewrite module.  I've tried a few things, but had no success.  I have the following rule in a web.config in a folder.  Everything at the folder level works fine, so servername.com/cmsvd/page.aspx redirects just fine.  However, when I have servername.com/cmsvd/reports/reportfile.aspx, that one does not redirect.  I assume it is something on my end.  I'm guessing it has to do with the {R:1}, but I don't know that.  any suggestions on how to also get /cmsvd/reports/reportfile.aspx to redirect as well?  My rule is listed below.  I can't hard code the number of folders in this, so I need it to work with everything below the /cmsvd folder.  fyi, servername.com and newservername.com are the same machine and same folder, I need the url to be rewritten and not get into an infinite loop.
TIA.
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)servername.com" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^servername.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url=https://newservername.com/CMSVD/{R:1} />
        </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>

